# Pandas unstack problems: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to unstack a multi-index with pandas and I am keep getting:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Given a dataset with four columns:

- id (string)
- date (string)
- location (string)
- value (float)

I first set a three-level multi-index:

```
In [37]: e.set_index(['id', 'date', 'location'], inplace=True)

In [38]: e
Out[38]: 
                                    value
id           date       location       
id1          2014-12-12 loc1        16.86
             2014-12-11 loc1        17.18
             2014-12-10 loc1        17.03
             2014-12-09 loc1        17.28
```

Then I try to unstack the location:

```
In [39]: e.unstack('location')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-bc1e237a0ed7> in <module>()
----> 1 e.unstack('location')
...
C:\Anaconda\envs\sandbox\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.pyc in _make_selectors(self)
    143 
    144         if mask.sum() < len(self.index):
--> 145             raise ValueError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
    146                              'cannot reshape')
    147 

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Are there any NaNs in your data?  There was [an unstack bug related to those](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4862).

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Could you give a small example DataFrame which demonstrates this issue (so we can just run your code and see if we get the same result)?

Comment: @BrenBarn There are no NAN in my dataset.

Comment: @AndyHayden I am using pandas 0.15.2. I will try to create a dataframe that reproduces the result, but so far, I have been unable to do so.

Comment: This is a very old question, however my two cents.. I was getting this error and while checking the data I found there are duplicates data in my excel cell. I was trying to break multiple rows in a cell to individual rows. Once I remove duplicates, this error is not anymore

Comment: Just to add to last comment, `df.drop_duplicates(['id','date','location'])` would remove the duplicates so that the operation can proceed. Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13833239/1769163

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here's an example DataFrame which show this, it has duplicate values with the same index. The question is, do you want to aggregate these or keep them as multiple rows?

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   0  1  2      3
0  1  2  a  16.86
1  1  2  a  17.18
2  1  4  a  17.03
3  2  5  b  17.28

In [12]: df.pivot_table(values=3, index=[0, 1], columns=2, aggfunc='mean')  # desired?
Out[12]:
2        a      b
0 1
1 2  17.02    NaN
  4  17.03    NaN
2 5    NaN  17.28

In [13]: df1 = df.set_index([0, 1, 2])

In [14]: df1
Out[14]:
           3
0 1 2
1 2 a  16.86
    a  17.18
  4 a  17.03
2 5 b  17.28

In [15]: df1.unstack(2)
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

---

One solution is to `reset_index` (and get back to `df`) and use `pivot_table`.

```
In [16]: df1.reset_index().pivot_table(values=3, index=[0, 1], columns=2, aggfunc='mean')
Out[16]:
2        a      b
0 1
1 2  17.02    NaN
  4  17.03    NaN
2 5    NaN  17.28
```

Another option (if you don't want to aggregate) is to append a dummy level, unstack it, then drop the dummy level...

Comment: I had a large dataframe that I was fairly sure had the correct indices. Turned out that some of the sub-dataframes were being created incorrectly, and indices were duplicated. `np.where(df.index.duplicated())` is a real help here.

Answer (score 70):

There's a far more simpler solution to tackle this.

The reason why you get `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` is because, once you unstack "`Location`", then the remaining index columns "`id`" and "`date`" combinations are no longer unique.

You can avoid this by retaining the default index column (row #) and while setting the index using "`id`", "`date`" and "`location`", add it in "`append`" mode instead of the default overwrite mode.

So use,

```
e.set_index(['id', 'date', 'location'], append=True)
```

Once this is done, your index columns will still have the default index along with the set indexes. And `unstack` will work.

Let me know how it works out.

Comment: 2 hours trying to figure this out, couldn't believe it could be as hard as some of the posts I've seen.

Comment: I've got 13 tabs open searching to solve this same issue and `append=True` is the only thing than worked. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome and easy solution! Made my day!

Comment: append=True create a few columns with the same name. I am not sure this is the original intent of the OP.

Comment: Why do you say `once you unstack "Location", then the remaining index columns "id" and "date" combinations are no longer unique`? They seem unique to me.

Comment: Are column names then _lost_? Like, the column of a DataFrame are `print(modis_albedo_products.columns)`: `Index(['myd21', 'modis_product', 'correlation'], dtype='object')`, then doing `temp = modis_albedo_products.set_index(['myd21', 'modis_product', 'correlation'], append=True)` will give `print(temp.columns)`: `Index([], dtype='object')`.

Comment: Another thing to watch out for - if at some point you lost your column labels, you'll get this error.

Comment: Appending to the index completely defeats the purpose of using a MultiIndex so it can help you group entities.

Answer (score 8):

I had such problem. In my case problem was in data - my column 'information' contained 1 unique value and it caused error

**UPDATE**: to correct work 'pivot' pairs (id_user,information) cannot have duplicates

**It works**:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_user':[1,2,3,4,4,5,5], 
'information':['phon','phon','phone','phone1','phone','phone1','phone'], 
'value': [1, '01.01.00', '01.02.00', 2, '01.03.00', 3, '01.04.00']})
df2.pivot(index='id_user', columns='information', values='value')
```

**it doesn't work**:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_user':[1,2,3,4,4,5,5], 
'information':['phone','phone','phone','phone','phone','phone','phone'], 
'value': [1, '01.01.00', '01.02.00', 2, '01.03.00', 3, '01.04.00']})
df2.pivot(index='id_user', columns='information', values='value')
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021196/6088984

Comment: The not working scenario works if it contains unique values for id_user.