# Pandas way to "pivot" string columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Is there a smart function which will "pivot" data frame containing strings?

> A1 | B1 | C1
>   A2  | B1 | C2
>   A1  | B2 | C3
>   A1  | B3 | C4
>   A3  | B1 | C5
>   A2  | B2 | C6

Desired output:

> ___| B1 | B2 | B3
>   A1 | C1 | C3 | C4
>   A2 | C2 | C6
>   A3 | C5

Comment: Did you try anything so far? and if you please provide more description to the desired output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate some data in the same way and there I have some problems. Unfortunately I didn't test data frame which I set as an example. And obviously it works.

Comment: I was recieving: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape, and I have fixed it based on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651079/pandas-unstack-problems-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-re)

Answer (score 1):

You already mention `pivot`

```
df
Out[265]: 
    A   B   C
0  A1  B1  C1
1  A2  B1  C2
2  A1  B2  C3
3  A1  B3  C4
4  A3  B1  C5
5  A2  B2  C6

df.pivot('A','B','C')
Out[266]: 
B   B1    B2    B3
A                 
A1  C1    C3    C4
A2  C2    C6  None
A3  C5  None  None
```