# How to compute a ratio between two filtered variables in a 'tidy' Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following Pandas data frame in 'tidy' (long) format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                          'Metric':['Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty'],
                          'Sector':['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
                          'Value':[45000, 70000, 65000, 40000, 65000, 63000, 2700, 4400, 3400, 3000, 4700, 5700, 1500, 2000, 2500, 1300, 2000, 2450],
                       })
```

I'm trying to compute the ratio between Orders to Sales, broken down by Manufacturer and Sector.

I've tried a few approaches (e.g. groupby, transform, etc.) based on the answers provided in [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby/23377155#23377155), but was unsuccessful with any of these (likely due to the data being structured a bit differently, and the lack of filtering required).

The ultimate goal is to make a bar plot displaying the Orders to Sales ratio broken down by Sector and Manufacturer, similar to the following:

[image]

**Question:  how would I compute the ratio between Orders to Sales (broken down by Manufacturer and Sector) as a means to plot the result?**

Thanks in advance!

---

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
**UPDATE**/////////////////////////////////////////////

If we amend the data frame to include another column which results in duplicate data in one of the indices, we get an error.

Here is the updated data frame with a new `City` column:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['Ford', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                          'Metric':['Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty'],
                          'Sector':['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
                          'Value':[45000, 70000, 90000, 65000, 40000, 65000, 63000, 2700, 4400, 3400, 3000, 4700, 5700, 1500, 2000, 2500, 1300, 2000, 2450],
                          'City': ['Frankfurt', 'Bremen', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles', 'Dresden', 'Munich', 'Cologne', 'Miami', 'Atlanta', 'Phoenix', 'Nuremberg', 'Dusseldorf', 'Leipzig', 'Houston', 'San Diego', 'San Francisco']
                       })
```

Running the following:

```
s1=df.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Orders'").Value
s2=df.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Sales'").Value

s1.div(s2).unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

Results in the following error:

```
`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`
```

The reason is because of these duplicates:

```
Manufacturer   Metric   Sector    Value    City
Ford           Orders   Germany   45000    Frankfurt
Ford           Orders   Germany   70000    Bremen
```

I tried to treat this use case with the following from [Pandas unstack problems: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651079/pandas-unstack-problems-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-re):

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(values = 'Value', index = ['Manufacturer', 'Metric'], aggfunc='sum')
```

But, I was unsuccessful and still get the error message about duplicate values.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I created the code as a graph comparing orders and sales by manufacturer and country of production.

```
sales = df[df['Metric'] == 'Sales'].set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).groupby(level=[0,1])['Value'].sum().to_frame('Sales')

orders = df[df['Metric'] == 'Orders'].set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).groupby(level=[0,1])['Value'].sum().to_frame('Orders')
df2 = orders.merge(sales, on=['Manufacturer','Sector'])

df2
              Orders    Sales
Manufacturer Sector     
BMW      Germany    65000   3400
         USA        63000   5700
Ford     Germany    115000  2700
         USA        40000   3000
Mercedes Germany    90000   4400
         USA        65000   4700

df2.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some additional testing, I have found a solution:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['Ford', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                          'Metric':['Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty'],
                          'Sector':['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
                          'Value':[45000, 70000, 90000, 65000, 40000, 65000, 63000, 2700, 4400, 3400, 3000, 4700, 5700, 1500, 2000, 2500, 1300, 2000, 2450],
                          'City': ['Frankfurt', 'Bremen', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles', 'Dresden', 'Munich', 'Cologne', 'Miami', 'Atlanta', 'Phoenix', 'Nuremberg', 'Dusseldorf', 'Leipzig', 'Houston', 'San Diego', 'San Francisco']
                       })

temp_table = test_df.reset_index().pivot_table(values = 'Value', index = ['Manufacturer', 'Metric', 'Sector'], aggfunc='sum')


df_new = temp_table.reset_index()

s1=df_new.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Orders'").Value
s2=df_new.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Sales'").Value

s1.div(s2).unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Thanks to @YOBEN_S for the solution to the original data set and for inspiring this solution!