# How do I turn a categorical column into the level 0 of a column multi-index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

If I have a data-frame like so:

[image]

generated with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'dataset': ['dataset1']*2 + ['dataset2']*2 + ['dataset3']*2,
                   'frame': [1,2] * 3,
                   'result1': np.random.randn(6),
                   'result2': np.random.randn(6),
                   'result3': np.random.randn(6),
                   'method': ['A']*3 + ['B']*3
                  })
df = df.set_index(['dataset','frame'])
df
```

How can I transform it, so that I have multi-indexed columns, where the values in column `'method'` are level 0 of the multi-index.
Missing values should be filled in like, e.g. like so:

[image]
The final goal is that I want to be able to easily compare corresponding values in the columns 'result1',  'result2',  'result3' between method 'A' and 'B'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `method` to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('method', append=True).unstack().swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
method                 A                             B                    
                 result1   result2   result3   result1   result2   result3
dataset  frame                                                            
dataset1 1      1.488609  1.130858  0.409016       NaN       NaN       NaN
         2      0.676011  0.645002  0.102751       NaN       NaN       NaN
dataset2 1     -0.418451  0.106414 -1.907722       NaN       NaN       NaN
         2           NaN       NaN       NaN -0.806521  0.422155  1.100224
dataset3 1           NaN       NaN       NaN  0.555876  0.124207 -1.402325
         2           NaN       NaN       NaN -0.705504 -0.837953 -0.225081

#if need remove second level
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Comment: I just realized that for my actual usage `append=True` is critical in `set_index('method',append=True)` or I will get the error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`
This is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855662/653770).