# how to reshape a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have a dataframe that looks like that:

```
    date    nom_de_produit  vl  nbre_part   actif_net_part  collecte
4419404 2009-12-15  AIS SCHELCHER EQUITY CONVICTIONS    8,601.13    1,772.00    15.24   15.24
1711479 2009-12-15  AIS SCHELCHER EQUITY CONVICTIONS    24.42   16,535,219.00   403.79  403.79
4419403 2009-12-16  AIS SCHELCHER EQUITY CONVICTIONS    8,698.79    1,772.00    15.41   0.00
1711478 2009-12-16  AIS SCHELCHER EQUITY CONVICTIONS    24.70   16,532,917.00   408.36  -0.06
4419402 2009-12-17  AIS SCHELCHER EQUITY CONVICTIONS    8,608.85    1,772.00    15.25   0.00
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4490513 2023-09-07  FEDERAL INDICIEL APAL   292,228.55  9.00    2.63    0.00
1551271 2023-09-08  FEDERAL INDICIEL JAPON  268.70  269,261.00  72.35   0.00
4501848 2023-09-08  FEDERAL INDICIEL JAPON  130,979.00  0.00    0.00    0.00
13857662    2023-09-08  FEDERAL INDICIEL JAPON  130.67  42,933.00   5.61    0.00
13859487    2023-09-08  FEDERAL INDICIEL JAPON  165.40  1,135.00    0.19    0.00
```

I would like to reshape it with date as index and 'nom_de_produit' as columns name with values that are 'vl', 'nbre_part', 'actifs_net_part' and 'collecte' as values.

I tried:

```
pivoted = df.pivot(index="date", 
                   columns= 'nom_de_produit', 
                   values=['vl', 'nbre_part', 'actif_net_part', 'collecte'])
```

but get an error message which is:
`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: If you have duplicates, then you need to aggregate. You likely need a `pivot_table`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651079/pandas-unstack-problems-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-re?

Comment: i tried: pivoted = df.pivot_table(index='date', 
                         columns= 'nom_de_produit', 
                         values='vl'
                         ) but get an error message:  KeyError: 'vl'

Comment: first, try a group sum using the date field then follow with a pivot table

Comment: `KeyError: 'vl'` means that you used an incorrect column name. What is the output of `list(df)`?