# Pivoting a pandas dataframe with duplicate index values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has rows for each user joining my site and making a purchase.

```
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+--------+-----+
|   | uid |        msg         |  _time  | gender | age |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+--------+-----+
| 0 |   1 | confirmed_settings | 1/29/15 | M      |  37 |
| 1 |   1 | sale               | 4/13/15 | M      |  37 |
| 2 |   3 | confirmed_settings | 4/19/15 | M      |  35 |
| 3 |   4 | confirmed_settings | 2/21/15 | M      |  21 |
| 4 |   5 | confirmed_settings | 3/28/15 | M      |  18 |
| 5 |   4 | sale               | 3/15/15 | M      |  21 |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+--------+-----+
```

I would like to change the dataframe so that each row is unique for a uid and there is a columns called `sale` and `confirmed_settings` which have the timestamp of the action. Note that not every user has a `sale`, but every user has a `confirmed_settings`.  Like below:

```
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
|   | uid | confirmed_settings |  sale   |  _time  | gender | age |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
| 0 |   1 | 1/29/15            | 4/13/15 | 1/29/15 | M      |  37 |
| 1 |   3 | 4/19/15            | null    | 4/19/15 | M      |  35 |
| 2 |   4 | 2/21/15            | 3/15/15 | 2/21/15 | M      |  21 |
| 3 |   5 | 3/28/15            | null    | 3/28/15 | M      |  18 |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
```

To do this, I am trying:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='uid', columns='msg', values='_time').reset_index()
df1 = df1.merge(df[['uid', 'gender', 'age']].drop_duplicates(), on='uid')
```

But I get this error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

How can I pivot a df with duplicate index values to transform my dataframe?

---

Edit:
`df1 = df.pivot_table(index='uid', columns='msg', values='_time').reset_index()`

gives this error `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` but im not even sure that is the right path to go on.

Comment: There was an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232275/pandas-pivot-warning-about-repeated-entries-on-index) post where someone used pivot_table() instead of pivot and it resolved the same error, might be worth trying?

Comment: @benjamin I saw that post and tried earlier, but got this error - `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` and decided not continue down that path, because I understand that error even less. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try doing it again, only this time coerce your 'uid' column into a numeric type by running this first: `df['uid'] = df['uid'].astype(int)`

Comment: @benjamin still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry, that's as best as I know for the moment. Hope someone has an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is the data frame that you have as input :

```
    uid               msg   _time   gender  age
0   1   confirmed_settings  1/29/15 M       37
1   1   sale                4/13/15 M       37
2   3   confirmed_settings  4/19/15 M       35
3   4   confirmed_settings  2/21/15 M       21
4   5   confirmed_settings  3/28/15 M       18
5   4   sale                3/15/15 M       21

y = x.pivot(index='uid', columns='msg', values='_time')
x.join(y).drop('msg', axis=1)
```

gives you:

```
    uid _time   gender  age     confirmed_settings  sale
0   1   1/29/15     M   37                    NaN   NaN
1   1   4/13/15     M   37                1/29/15   4/13/15
2   3   4/19/15     M   35                    NaN   NaN
3   4   2/21/15     M   21                4/19/15   NaN
4   5   3/28/15     M   18                2/21/15   3/15/15
5   4   3/15/15     M   21                3/28/15   NaN
```

Comment: Still getting this error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` on just executing this bit of code `y = x.pivot(index='uid', columns='msg', values='_time')`

Comment: I'm on pandas version 0.16. Which one are you on ?

Comment: my version is `0.15.2`

Comment: Check if the other answer works ? Or upgrade  to 0.16 ?

Comment: Going to try an upgrade

Comment: Ok - so I upgraded to 16.0 and it didn't solve the problem, but I think I found my issue.  My data set is much larger than my example, and there must be some data error where a user has two sales or two confirm_settings.  I'm going to try and cleanse the data better and your solution should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76479/discussion-between-fixxxer-and-meepl).

Answer (score 8):

I suspect there are indeed duplicate `uid`-`msg` entries/keys (e.g. `uid` 2 has 2 confirmed_settings entries under `msg`), which you alluded to in the comments for fixxxer's answer. If there are, you can't use `pivot`, because you can't tell it how to treat the different values encountered during aggregation (count? max? mean? sum?). Note that the Index error is an error on the Index of the resulting pivoted table `df1`, not the original DataFrame `df`.

`pivot_table` lets you do it however with the `aggfunc` argument. How about something like this?

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index = 'uid', columns = 'msg', values = '_time', aggfunc = len)
```

This will help you figure out which user-msg records have duplicate entries (anything with over 1), and after cleaning them out, you can use `pivot` on `df` to successfully pivot `_time`.

Comment: In my case I had a timeseries-indexed dataframe. With this pivot_table I discovered (what's obvious in retrospect) that in November "fall back", there are two hours with the same timestamps, same `"columns"` (here `'hub'`), but different `'values'`. In that case I used `df = df[~df.duplicated(subset = ['Date', 'hub'], keep='first')]` to just throw away the second hour.

Answer (score 3):

You can use groupby to aggregate by the common factors, take the max of time to get the most recent dates, and then unstack the msg to view confirmed_settings and sale side by side:

```
df.groupby(['uid', 'msg', 'gender', 'age']).time.max().unstack('msg')

msg            confirmed_settings     sale
uid gender age                            
1   M      37             1/29/15  4/13/15
3   M      35             4/19/15      NaN
4   M      21             2/21/15  3/15/15
5   M      18             3/28/15      NaN
```